# The bound $\mathbb E(e^{tX})\le \cosh(t)$ for all real $t$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a real random variable with $\mathbb E(X)=0$ and $|X|\le 1$. I wonder if the following bound is true for all $t\in \mathbb R$:

$$\mathbb E(e^{tX})\le \cosh(t):=\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}.$$

I want to obtain the bound $E(e^{tX})\le e^{t^2/2}$ and use this as an intermediate step.

Comment: I'm not sure that the bound that you state is your goal is true. If I was to guess, I would guess that it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and notice that $x \mapsto e^{tx}$ is convex. Thus the graph of $x \mapsto e^{tx}$ on $x \in [-1, 1]$ lies below the line segment joining $(-1,e^{-t})$ and $(1, e^{t})$. Rephrasing this statement, we get

\begin{align*}
e^{tx} \leq e^{-t} + \frac{e^{t} - e^{-t}}{2} (x + 1), \qquad -1 \leq x \leq 1
\end{align*}

Plugging $x = X(\omega)$ and taking expectation with respect to $\omega$, we get

$$ \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[ e^{-t} + \frac{e^{t} - e^{-t}}{2} (X + 1) \right] = \cosh(t), $$

where the balancedness assumption $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$ is utilized in the last step.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ be the convex hull of $\{(x,\exp(tx)): -1\le x \le 1\}\subseteq\mathbb R^2$.  The point $(0,Ee^{tX})$ lies in $C$, so it suffices to check that $C\cap\{(0,y):y\in\mathbb R\}$ is the line segment connecting $(0,1)$ and $(0,\cosh t)$.